# Postgres Install - PGADMIN 4 not working in Windows Server 2008

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I download postgresql-9.6.2-3-windows-x64.exe and installed it without any warning in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.
But PGADMIN 4 shows a dark screen only.

I tried several approaches unsuccessfuly.

Comment: pgadmin4 is python based. Are you python libraries fully upto date ?

Comment: I have similar troubles.  This appears to be a known issue https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2206

Comment: Response from pgadmin-support mail group:

Please try one of the Mac/Windows test builds at https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/. I would strongly advise doing a complete uninstall before installing, to ensure no old, unused files are left behind.

Comment: @Mokadillion, I have been installed only the executable file, nothing more. I dont know if the entire library is up to date because, in fact, I dont have enough skills to verify it.

Comment: @n33rma, pgadmin4-1.4-x86.exe version from that site works fine.

Comment: pgadmin4-1.5-x86.exe from pgadmin.org website doesn't run on Windows Server 2012R2. Shows a splash screen, then nothing. Background process remains, uses 0% CPU and memory use doesn't vary.

Comment: @user911810 Thank you, I was using Windows 2008 R2, after 2days of struggle below solution worked for me.  `pgadmin4-1.4-x86.exe`   https://pgadmin-archive.postgresql.org/pgadmin4/v1.4/windows/index.html